# python - history file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a project

I'm making a text browser and I need help

I have a history file that every url and time, put in the history file like:

> www.youtube.com 2016-06-29 13:47:15.986000
>
> www.youtube.com 2016-06-29 13:47:22.416000
>
> www.youtube.com 2016-06-29 13:47:31.962000
>
> www.youtube.com 2016-06-29 13:47:40.713000
>
> www.youtube.com 2016-06-29 13:47:49.193000

I need to make a `remove` func that gets a url, and removes all the lines

(the lines separated by "\n")

this is the code of history file:

```
def Update_history(url):
    thistime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    urlat = url + " " + thistime
    history = open("somthing.txt" , "w")
    history.write(urlat)
    history.write("\n")
```

Please help my, it's for tomorrow!

Comment: Demanding people to help you because you waited until the last minute generates downvotes. Instead, get rid of that last part of the question and explain why you have been unsucessful with your remove method. What specifically are you having trouble with and what code have you tried? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to delete this lines from the file, try this:

```
import os

def removeUrl(url):
    url_file = "url.txt"
    fileIn = open(url_file, 'r')
    fileOut = open("temp.txt", 'w')
    for line in fileIn:
        if url not in line:
            fileOut.write(line)
    fileIn.close()
    fileOut.close()

    os.remove(url_file)
    os.rename("temp.txt", url_file)

removeUrl("www.youtube.com")
```